# Facebook events are only registering some random ones

Tags: facebook, events

I use the Facebook library to record events and carry out marketing campaigns in my application, however since 12/20/2023 it has been recording only a few events at random, for example it has product x, y and z, when the user clicks in the product it registers this access, and in the Facebook panel it registers only product x and product y and z does not register. I'm using the latest version of the SDK for Android and IOS, my app is in Flutter, but I made this part of the code native for both Android and IOS. I believe that the app's configuration is correct because it records some events, if it were wrong it would not record any.

I followed all the Facebook documentation, tried to create several other logs, and in the same way, some are recorded, such as "test event" and "opened application" while "test_event" did not record, all being recorded in sequence. The function that registers is the same, it just changes the string that I pass as a parameter for this function to register the event.